# Images in Strapi media library not showing

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

I just deployed my strapi cms to heroku, and the problem is when I add assets into media library, the images will not showing after few minutes, [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKNEh.png)

The URL of the images exists on the API, but when I check it manually, it shown 'not found' message. Any solution of this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This Issue may be solved. According to the [@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary)

According to that, we need to add the below code to `./config/middlewares.js` file.

```js
module.exports = [
  // ...
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
          'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'dl.airtable.com', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          'media-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'dl.airtable.com', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
];
```

This should resolve the issue and we should be able to see the image thumbnails in the Strapi media library.